# Selecting a smaller object hidden inside another big object

Tags: selection-tools

How can I select a hidden object to `rotate` , `remove` or `resize` which is hidden inside another bigger object ("hidden" means a smaller object is inside another bigger object) ?
Clicking with the right mouse button on the bigger object may help but that is not an obvious approach as I don't know exactly at which position the tiny object is located.Moreover , What about a tiny object inside a super big object ? (Like a luggage in an airplane model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, and in the case where you have a large scene with many objects, selection is done more easily using the  [Outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways I use to deal with this situation in my own workflow. In some cases I select one or the other of the objects, either the outer or inner, and move it to a different layer, make the edits, and then move the item originally moved back to the other layer. In other cases, I'll use the hide facility in Blender (<kbd>H</kbd> key) to make the outer object invisible, and when I am done making edits, I'll unhide the hidden object using the <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> key combination.

As commoner suggested in another answer, sometimes I use the oulener to make the selection.